# Pentaho date format issue

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

my input excel sheet has the field with two different types of values column in the format YYYY/MM/DD

[image]

Now, when I have added the excel sheet into Pentaho the columns along with datatype I got which shows string datatype in the date formats column. which you can see below

[image]

After this, I tried to integrate with postgres but I am unable to find the result the error which I got attached below

[image]

Updated

I tried with the given timestamp format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` this works fine for me but this format `yyyy/MM/dd hh.00.00` is not present in the format column.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the answer did you added select values step and changes the format? How does your latest transformation looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a column named `Date` in the field definition tab. Choose `Date` [data type] from the Dropdown box in the row `date` [column name] and `timestamp` [column name].

Try to get the data in the `Excel Input` step. If it does not work, try to write  `yyyy/MM/dd` in the `Format` column for the `date` field and `yyyy/MM/dd hh.00.00` for `timestamp` field. Note that the format is most probably unnecessary for the `Excel Input`.

Once you can get all the row in the `Excel Input` with a preview limit 0, **and not before**, try to put the data in the Postgres database.

Normally it should work. If not, use a `Select Step` which has a tab `Meta-data`, to change among other the format of the dates. Chose a format accepted by Postgres. Again, this change of format is most probably unnecessary.

To explain what happens under the wood, remember each field in the PDI has a type. You define `time` and `timestamp` as `string`. It is not an issue by itself, until you try to put those string in the database, which no not accept such date formats. The best way is to use the date type (which DO NOT have a format until you want to read or write them).

Answer (score 0):

Select or put the corresponding format in [Format] column on [Fields] Tab.