# Pentaho mapping values to numeric

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

**Summary**

I am trying to map integer values using `value mapper` and integrate with the postgres. I am trying a simple test convert
1 to 100,
2 to 200 and so on and save it

**Steps**

Take an excel file and add into excel input.The sample data I have shown below.
[image]

Then link excel input with the `value mapper` and set the column name of the numeric datatype in fieldname after I added the source and target value. which you can below
[image]
In the final step, after integrating with the database when i executed I got some error message which I have attached below.

[image]

**Note:**
The above steps is working absolutely fine with the string values.

Comment: Preview the excel input data and check whether values are coming as 1,2,3 or 1.0,2.0,3.0 if .0 is coming then you have to map with 1.0,2.0 instead of 1,2,3 ...

Comment: I tried this also but got an error

Comment: The value which i get is 1.0 and i tried to map with 1.0 but its not working

Comment: I tried this solution and working fine with number data-type,so problem is not with value mapper step, if you are getting and error which you have attached in question then it is related with insertion and it looks like Table is not accepting null values.

Comment: hey, I tried the mapping with 1.0, 2.0 again. I got an error but this time what I observed the query takes a numeric value as a string **Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "public".test_pentahoo (num) VALUES ( '100.0') was aborted.  Call getNextException** to see the cause

Comment: I don’t know how you have designed the ktr but if you are getting error because of a format or data-type then you can convert it using select values step before it inserts into database.

Comment: Thank you very much select values works

Comment: Hey, Can you please look at this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814937/pentaho-date-format-issue/49821238#49821238

Comment: in above question answer is already accepted.

Comment: no, that was partially correct with the date format that works fines but in  this kind of **[yyyy/MM/dd hh.00.00]** timestamp case its not working

Comment: yes, I followed all the given steps multiples times but got the same error. Also, I am unable to change the timestamp type to date and format like ** yyyy/MM/dd hh.00.00 **